# How to create heredocs on RAM instead of disk?

Tags: bash, debian, btrfs, here-document

Saving following script in a file:

```bash
cat <<EOF | wc -l
$HOME
abc
$(hostname)
EOF
```

and executing it gives the following error:

```
$ ./a.sh 
./a.sh: line 1: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

My Debian thinks that there is no space left on the device (which is not true, but it's out of our context). However I have a plenty of RAM space. Since my tools (scripts) also refuse to work because of this error, I'm unable to resolve the actual "no space left" issue. What can I do to make my scripts use the RAM for the "heredoc" handling process in order to get them working at least, so that I can move forward to resolve the actual problem by using my tools?

Comment: `which is not true, but it's out of our context` since you're using btrfs, do you really understand about "disk full" error in btrfs? Have you balance the disk? In that case it's really relevant in the context

Comment: The irrelevant part is that yes, I have to do something in order to open up some space on my disk but I need to write/run some small scripts to make this happen. I need to save some small file to perform the maintenance we are talking about.

Comment: no, you don't need to save any script, just run `btrfs balance start -m /` directly and you'll get some more free space, and then you can do further full balancing

Answer (score 4):

Point the `$TMPDIR` variable to some directory that is on a RAM disk/tmpfs, since that's the variable that determines where the shell (at least `bash`) creates its temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

Find a mount with the `tmpfs` filesystem

```
grep tmpfs /etc/mtab
```

in my case, one of the lines is

```
 tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=808468k,nr_inodes=202117,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

then as @telcoM mentions do

```
export TMPDIR=/run/user/1000
```

(or use that for a file, like `wc -l $(hostname) >> /run/user/1000/myexample`)

BTW, is that `$(hostname)` just an example or what do you expect from that?

Comment: `$(hostname)` was just an example, I didn't really care its output. BTW, I overcome the problem by deleting some files from `/tmp`, so I probably will apply your solution next time I encounter the problem (or simulate somehow). I think I'll come across with it again in the near future.